# Does ArcGIS Online include High Speed Rail in its network analysis?

Tags: arcgis-online, network-analyst, network, analysis

I'd like to run an OD Matrix using network analyst in Europe and Asia to study high speed rail.

Does ArcGIS online include HSR (such as the AVE in Spain or the TGV in France) in its analysis?

Answer (score 3):

[ArcGIS Online Network Analysis](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/guide-books/extensions/network-analyst/what-are-arcgis-online-network-services-10-2-.htm) services are based on road network data (from various vendors such as HERE/TomTom and some others in several countries) and do not include railways. You would need to obtain the data and build your own network dataset.